# What is Tally query language?

Tags: tally

What is Tally query language? I searched online but I didn't get anything on TQL. I got something about Tally definition language. Is there any difference between Tally query language and Tally definition language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called **Natural Query Language**, and has documentation available **[here](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/te9rel61/SMS/Natural_Language.htm)**.

> Natural Query Language acts as an interface between the user and a company connected to Tally Software Services (TSS). It is a way of communicating in normal words, following the grammar or syntax of a spoken language. Natural Query Language uses queries composed with basic, non-technical, English words.
>
> **How It Works**
>
> To retrieve information from a company connected to Tally.NET, the user types a query on the mobile phone and sends it to a designated number. Tally.ERP 9 converts the query to a format which the database understands and extracts the required information from the company. The user receives a response with information in a simple format.

Comment: Thank you for your help. can please provide one example with tally.Erp9 that means where to write sql query on Tally software.

Answer (score 2):

Tally query language:-

it's another name is Natural Query Language acts as an interface between the user and a company connected to Tally Software Services (TSS). Natural Query Language uses queries composed of basic, non-technical, English words.

Tally definition language:-

it's including working with different Units of Measures.it's the application development language of Tally and using the application is build than generate a TCP extension file. That file copy-paste in install location of tally erp 9.

Answer (score 2):

Natural Query Language acts as an interface between the user and a company connected to Tally Software Services (TSS). It is a way of communicating in normal words, following the grammar or syntax of a spoken language. Natural Query Language uses queries composed with basic, non-technical, English words.

To retrieve information from a company connected to Tally[.]net, the user types a query on the mobile phone and sends it to a designated number. Tally.ERP 9 converts the query to a format which the database understands and extracts the required information from the company. The user receives a response with information in a simple format.

Example:

1.Working Capital ( Returns Working Capital)
2.Ledger Kotak Bank Address / Closing Balance / Account Name ( Returns Detailed Ledger of Kotak Bank)